# InputStream and OutputStream abstract methods

Tags: java, inputstream, abstract, outputstream

I've been exploring the java.io package a lot lately, and I've been wondering where can I find the exact processes that the abstract classes inside InputStream and OutputStream do.

I'm dazzled because, at least according to the source code, the core methods are all abstract (e.g. `InputStream.read()` and `OutputStream.write(int b)`). I'm especially concerned by the close methods, whose javadocs explicitly say they do nothing:

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.
>
> The `close` method of `InputStream` does nothing.

Well, input streams obviously write while output streams read, and definitely `close()` has to do the flushing and resource releasing.

Somebody able to give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes are abstract since in that way they can be easily extended and the implementor classes could use the Decorator Pattern (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707195/1065197)). With the decorator pattern, the implementor class can add dynamic functionality at runtime. For example: have an `InputStream` that can read a File using `FileInputStream` that can read serialized objects using `ObjectInputStream`. How to accomplish this?

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/file.dat"));
```

Comment: Indeed many streams inherit from these abstract classes. However, without using any inherited class, both `inputstream` and `outputstream` work and do something. They can indeed send and receive bytes. I'm asking about that core phase of the process, without any extended classes. :) Any ideas?

Comment: @Ruluk if you mean to use plain `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, you simply can't since they are `abstract` classes. You **always** need to use an implementation of these classes. Note that the implementation class contains the real logic/work.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I thought it did something because I used them directly in one tutorial, but now I analyzed further and they are just base streams that reference an offspring class.

Comment: @Ruluk if the answer solves your problem then click on the check below the arrows to mark this post as the answer